# Python - How to compare consecutive rows and take difference of another corresponding column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am quite new to python and am hoping someone would help me with this.
I have a data frame like this:

```
dc  region  banner  input_date  week        qty  general
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-02  161 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-02  130 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-03  167 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-03  158 dc_input    
PQR SE      GHQ    2020-03-01   2020-01-04  115 dc_input    
PQR SE      GHQ    2020-03-01   2020-01-04  100 dc_input
```

My output would look like this:

```
dc  region  banner  input_date  week        qty  general
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-02  161 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-02  130 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-03  167 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-03  158 dc_input    
PQR SE      GHQ    2020-03-01   2020-01-04  115 dc_input    
PQR SE      GHQ    2020-03-01   2020-01-04  100 dc_input    
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-02  31  sub_output
ABC NE      XYZ    2020-03-01   2020-01-03  9   sub_output
PQR SE      GHQ    2020-03-01   2020-01-04  15  sub_output
```

I want to check row by row for equality and if they are identical I would take a difference of their corresponding quantity and append it to the quantity column as a new row.
**Example - The first two rows are identical (except qty) so I need a diff of qty which is 31 and append the row + diff of qty as a new row.**

Would someone be able to help with the python code to obtain the above output?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code and output examples as text, don't link to photos - we're not going to follow links from anonymous sources. Make it easy for us to help you!

Comment: what if more than 2 rows are identical?

Comment: @Sociopath In my use case its only two identical rows. It would be helpful if you can provide a solution to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Sort the values in the df by all columns including `qty` so the diff is always positve.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['dc','region','banner','input_date','week','qty','general'])
```

Set the index and group by the columns you want to compare. For each group get the `diff()` and `dropna()` (this is to eliminate the same rows of the group) and `reset_index` to get all the columns. Now this will give you a dataframe with the rows that are matching and `qty` with the `diff()`

```
df2 = df.set_index(compare_cols).groupby(compare_cols)['qty'].diff().dropna().reset_index()
df2['general'] = 'sub_output'
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    dc region banner  input_date        week     general   qty
0  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-02  sub_output  31.0
1  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-03  sub_output   9.0
2  PQR     SE    GHQ  2020-03-01  2020-01-04  sub_output  15.0
```

Finally, merge your original df with this grouped df with diff

```
df = (df.reset_index().merge(df2, how='outer').drop('index', axis=1))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dc region banner  input_date        week  qty     general
0  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-02  130    dc_input
1  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-02  161    dc_input
2  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-03  158    dc_input
3  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-03  167    dc_input
4  PQR     SE    GHQ  2020-03-01  2020-01-04  100    dc_input
5  PQR     SE    GHQ  2020-03-01  2020-01-04  115    dc_input
6  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-02   31  sub_output
7  ABC     NE    XYZ  2020-03-01  2020-01-03    9  sub_output
8  PQR     SE    GHQ  2020-03-01  2020-01-04   15  sub_output
```